# Plotting on a 3-D image in Python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a 3D image with x,y, and Z axis and a data frame with positions of a few points. I want to plot those points on that particular image(which is 3d). I am using python for coding. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Is it a 3d surface or a 2d image with color information in z axis ?

Comment: @mujjiga It is a 3d surface and has 3 color channels, you can count it as 4th axes.